# How to reduce the amoutn of if statements

Tags: javascript, html

So, in my HTML I have some elements that when clicked on they bring up some other code that I am adding dynamically with the map() function and the filter() function in JavaScript. Then I am accessing the dynamically added content by targeting them through using childNodes onto the parent item and the childNodes index.

Then I am using the same filtering to generate the code when I click on the dynamically added items. Also, I am using if statements and then pinpoint a class. What I want to know is there a way to not use so many if statements? So far I don't know any other way of doing it.

Here my code:

```js
const projectCards = [
    {
        id: 1,
        dataId: "TAFE",
        class: 1,
        title: "Identity System",
        category: "TAFE",
        img: "../img/image-plane.jpg",
        url: "../pages/graphic_design/tafe/tafe_company_identitySystem.html",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        dataId: "TAFE",
        class: 2,
        title: "Audition/Show Posters",
        category: "TAFE",
        img: "../img/image-plane.jpg",
        url: "../pages/graphic_design/tafe/tafe_show_posters.html",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        dataId: "TAFE",
        class: 3,
        title: "Programs",
        category: "TAFE",
        img: "../img/image-plane.jpg",
        url: "../pages/graphic_design/tafe/tafe_show_programs.html",
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        dataId: "TAFE",
        class: 4,
        title: "Tickets",
        category: "TAFE",
        img: "../img/image-plane.jpg",
        url: "../pages/graphic_design/tafe/tafe_show_tickets.html",
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        dataId: "TAFE",
        class: 5,
        title: "Postcards",
        category: "TAFE",
        img: "../img/image-plane.jpg",
        url: "../pages/graphic_design/tafe/tafe_newsletter.html",
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        dataId: "TAFE",
        class: 6,
        title: "Newsletter",
        category: "TAFE",
        img: "../img/image-plane.jpg",
        url: "../pages/graphic_design/tafe/tafe_postcards.html",
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        dataId: "CAHQ",
        class: 7,
        title: "Identity System",
        category: "CAHQ",
        img: "../img/image-currency.jpg",
        url: "../pages/graphic_design/cahq/cahq_identity_system.html",
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        dataId: "CAHQ",
        class: 8,
        title: "Marketing Materials",
        category: "CAHQ",
        img: "../img/image-currency.jpg",
        url: "../pages/graphic_design/cahq/cahq_identity_system.html",
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        dataId: "CAHQ",
        class: 9,
        title: "Website Icons",
        category: "CAHQ",
        img: "../img/image-currency.jpg",
        url: "../pages/graphic_design/cahq/cahq_website_icons.html",
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        dataId: "PWC",
        class: 10,
        title: "Identity System",
        category: "PWC",
        img: "../img/image-restaurant.jpg",
        url: "../pages/graphic_design/pilates/pwc_company_identitySystem.html",
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        dataId: "PWC",
        class: 11,
        title: "Marketing Materials",
        category: "PWC",
        img: "../img/image-restaurant.jpg",
        url: "../pages/graphic_design/pilates/pwc_marketing_materials.html",
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        dataId: "PE",
        class: 12,
        title: "Columbia-Wrightsville Bridge",
        category: "PE",
        img: "../img/image-restaurant.jpg",
        url: "../pages/graphic_design/photo_essays/columbia-wrightsville_bridge.html",
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        dataId: "PE",
        class: 13,
        title: "Shift Focus",
        category: "PE",
        img: "../img/image-currency.jpg",
        url: "../pages/graphic_design/photo_essays/shift_focus.html",
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        dataId: "PE",
        class: 14,
        title: "A Commuter's View",
        category: "PE",
        img: "../img/image-plane.jpg",
        url: "../pages/graphic_design/photo_essays/a_commuters_view.html",
    },
];

let projects = [{
    id: 1,
    dataId: "TAFE",
    title: "Identity System",
    description: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla tenetur ab odio. Rerum cumque distinctio eveniet illum ea omnis non iure repudiandae labore quas aut optio aliquam dolorem, delectus doloribus!',
    date: '2016 - present',
    client: 'TAFE (Theater Arts For Everyone)',
    role: 'Graphic Designer',
    projectType: 'Layout (color + graphics)',
    programClass1: 'ai',
    programClass2: 'id',
    program1: 'Ai',
    program2: 'Id',
    category: "1",
    img: "../img/image-plane.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    dataId: "2",
    title: "Identity System",
    description: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla tenetur ab odio. Rerum cumque distinctio eveniet illum ea omnis non iure repudiandae labore quas aut optio aliquam dolorem, delectus doloribus!',
    date: '2016 - present',
    client: 'College Admissions HQ',
    role: 'Graphic Designer',
    projectType: 'Layout (color + graphics)',
    programClass1: 'ai',
    programClass2: 'id',
    program1: 'Ai',
    program2: 'Id',
    category: "2",
    img: "https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature",
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    dataId: "3",
    title: "Identity System",
    description: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla tenetur ab odio. Rerum cumque distinctio eveniet illum ea omnis non iure repudiandae labore quas aut optio aliquam dolorem, delectus doloribus!',
    date: '2016 - present',
    client: 'Pilates Welness Center',
    role: 'Graphic Designer',
    projectType: 'Layout (color + graphics)',
    programClass1: 'ai',
    programClass2: 'id',
    program1: 'Ai',
    program2: 'Id',
    category: "3",
    img: "../img/image-restaurant.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    dataId: "14",
    title: "Identity System",
    description: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla tenetur ab odio. Rerum cumque distinctio eveniet illum ea omnis non iure repudiandae labore quas aut optio aliquam dolorem, delectus doloribus!',
    date: '2016 - present',
    client: 'Lish',
    role: 'Graphic Designer',
    projectType: 'Layout (color + graphics)',
    programClass1: 'ai',
    programClass2: 'id',
    program1: 'Ai',
    program2: 'Id',
    category: "14",
    img: "../img/image-restaurant.jpg",
  },

  {
    id: 5,
    dataId: "5",
    title: "Identity System",
    description: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla tenetur ab odio. Rerum cumque distinctio eveniet illum ea omnis non iure repudiandae labore quas aut optio aliquam dolorem, delectus doloribus!',
    date: '2016 - present',
    client: 'secondEncounter',
    role: 'Graphic Designer',
    projectType: 'Layout (color + graphics)',
    programClass1: 'ai',
    programClass2: 'id',
    program1: 'Ai',
    program2: 'Id',
    category: "5",
    img: "../img/image-restaurant.jpg",
  },

  {
    id: 5,
    dataId: "5",
    title: "Identity System",
    description: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla tenetur ab odio. Rerum cumque distinctio eveniet illum ea omnis non iure repudiandae labore quas aut optio aliquam dolorem, delectus doloribus!',
    date: '2016 - present',
    client: 'YOU',
    role: 'Graphic Designer',
    projectType: 'Layout (color + graphics)',
    programClass1: 'ai',
    programClass2: 'id',
    program1: 'Ai',
    program2: 'Id',
    category: "5",
    img: "../img/image-restaurant.jpg",
  },

  {
    id: 9,
    dataId: "9",
    title: "Identity System",
    description: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla tenetur ab odio. Rerum cumque distinctio eveniet illum ea omnis non iure repudiandae labore quas aut optio aliquam dolorem, delectus doloribus!',
    date: '2016 - present',
    client: 'ME',
    role: 'Graphic Designer',
    projectType: 'Layout (color + graphics)',
    programClass1: 'ai',
    programClass2: 'id',
    program1: 'Ai',
    program2: 'Id',
    category: "9",
    img: "../img/image-restaurant.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    dataId: 11,
    title: "Identity System",
    description: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla tenetur ab odio. Rerum cumque distinctio eveniet illum ea omnis non iure repudiandae labore quas aut optio aliquam dolorem, delectus doloribus!',
    date: '2016 - present',
    client: 'US',
    role: 'Graphic Designer',
    projectType: 'Layout (color + graphics)',
    programClass1: 'ai',
    programClass2: 'id',
    program1: 'Ai',
    program2: 'Id',
    category: "11",
    img: "../img/image-restaurant.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    dataId: "8",
    title: "Identity System",
    description: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla tenetur ab odio. Rerum cumque distinctio eveniet illum ea omnis non iure repudiandae labore quas aut optio aliquam dolorem, delectus doloribus!',
    date: '2016 - present',
    client: 'MINE',
    role: 'Graphic Designer',
    projectType: 'Layout (color + graphics)',
    programClass1: 'ai',
    programClass2: 'id',
    program1: 'Ai',
    program2: 'Id',
    category: "8",
    img: "../img/image-restaurant.jpg",
  },

];

const portfolioHeadingContainer = document.getElementById('portfolio__headingContainer');
const portfolioContentContainer = document.getElementById('portfolio_content_container');

const buttonContainer = document.querySelector('button-container');
const filterProjects = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-projects');
const projectsBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.projects-btn');
const portfolioGrid = document.querySelector('.portfolio__grid');
const portfolioContent = document.querySelector('.portfolio__content');

filterProjects.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        const category = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        let children = portfolioGrid.childNodes;
        const projectCategory = projectCards.filter(function(projectItem) {
            if (projectItem.category === category) {
              return projectItem;
            }
          });

          if (category === "all") {
            displayProjectItems(projectCards);
          } else {
            displayProjectItems(projectCategory);
          }

          if(children[1].classList.contains('2')) {
                children[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
                    const portfolioProject = projects.filter(function(portfolioProjectItems) {
                        if (portfolioProjectItems.id === 1) {
                            return portfolioProjectItems;
                        }
                    });

                    if (category === "all") {
                        projectProjects(projects);
                    } else {
                        projectProjects(portfolioProject);
                    }
                });

            console.log(children[1]);
          } else if (children[1].classList.contains('8')) {
                children[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
                    const portfolioProject = projects.filter(function(portfolioProjectItems) {
                        if (portfolioProjectItems.id === 8) {
                            return portfolioProjectItems;
                        }
                    });

                    if (category === "all") {
                        projectProjects(projects);
                    } else {
                        projectProjects(portfolioProject);
                    }
                });
                console.log(children[1]);
          } else if (children[1].classList.contains('11')) {
            children[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
                const portfolioProject = projects.filter(function(portfolioProjectItems) {
                    if (portfolioProjectItems.id === 11) {
                        return portfolioProjectItems;
                    }
                });

                if (category === "all") {
                    projectProjects(projects);
                } else {
                    projectProjects(portfolioProject);
                }
            });
            console.log(children[1]);
      } else {
        children[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
            const portfolioProject = projects.filter(function(portfolioProjectItems) {
                if (portfolioProjectItems.id === 13) {
                    return portfolioProjectItems;
                }
            });

            if (category === "all") {
                projectProjects(projects);
            } else {
                projectProjects(portfolioProject);
            }
        });
        console.log(children[1]);
       }
          
          if(children[2]) {
              if(children[2].classList.contains('3')) {
                children[2].addEventListener('click', function() {
                    const portfolioProject = projects.filter(function(portfolioProjectItems) {
                        if (portfolioProjectItems.id === 3) {
                            return portfolioProjectItems;
                        }
                    });

                    if (category === "all") {
                        projectProjects(projects);
                    } else {
                        projectProjects(portfolioProject);
                    }
                });
                console.log(children[2]);
              } else if(children[2].classList.contains('9')) {
                children[2].addEventListener('click', function() {
                    const portfolioProject = projects.filter(function(portfolioProjectItems) {
                        if (portfolioProjectItems.id === 9) {
                            return portfolioProjectItems;
                        }
                    });

                    if (category === "all") {
                        projectProjects(projects);
                    } else {
                        projectProjects(portfolioProject);
                    }
                });
                console.log(children[2]);
              } else {
                children[2].addEventListener('click', function() {
                    const portfolioProject = projects.filter(function(portfolioProjectItems) {
                        if (portfolioProjectItems.id === 14) {
                            return portfolioProjectItems;
                        }
                    });

                    if (category === "all") {
                        projectProjects(projects);
                    } else {
                        projectProjects(portfolioProject);
                    }
                });
                console.log(children[2]);
              }
            }
    });


    function displayProjectItems(projectItems) {
        let displayProjectItem = projectItems.map(function(item) {
          return `<a href="#" id="${item.id}" data-id="${item.dataId}" class="portfolio__item content-container ${item.class}">
                  <img class="portfolio__image" src="${item.img}" alt="TAFE Logo" />
                  <div class="portfolio__clientName">
                      <h3 class="portfolio__clientName-text">${item.title}</h3>
                  </div> <!-- end portfolio__clientName -->
              </a>`;
      
        });
      
        let displayTitle = projectItems.map(function(titleItem) {
            return `<h2 class="text-title ${titleItem.class} hide">${titleItem.category}</h2>`;
        });
      
      
        displayProjectItem = displayProjectItem.join("");
        portfolioGrid.innerHTML = displayProjectItem;
        
        displayTitle = displayTitle.join("");
        headerHero.innerHTML = displayTitle;
      }
});


function projectProjects(projectProjectsItems) {
    let didplayProjectsProjectsItems = projectProjectsItems.map(function(item) {
        return `
    <div id="${item.dataId}" class="${item.id}"><h2 class="projects__heading">${item.title}</h2>
        <div class="projects__info">
            <div class="projects__description">
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla tenetur ab odio. Rerum cumque distinctio eveniet illum ea omnis non iure repudiandae labore quas aut optio aliquam dolorem, delectus doloribus!
            </div> <!-- end project__description -->
            <div class="projects__ID">
                <p class="date">Created: ${item.date}</p>
                <p class="client">Client: ${item.client}</p>
                <p class="role">Role: ${item.role}</p>
                <p class="project-type">Project Type: ${item.projectType}</p>
                <p class="programs">Programs Used: <span class="${item.programClass1}">${item.program1}</span></p>
            </div> <!-- end project__header -->
        </div> <!-- end project__info -->
        <div class="projects__gallery">
            <div class="projects__image"><img src="../img/CAHQ/CAHQ-Brochure-Inside.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="projects__image"><img src="../img/image-confetti.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="projects__image"><img src="../img/image-confetti.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="projects__image"><img src="../img/image-confetti.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="projects__image"><img src="../img/image-confetti.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </div> 
    </div>`;

    });

    didplayProjectsProjectsItems = didplayProjectsProjectsItems.join("");
    portfolioContent.innerHTML = didplayProjectsProjectsItems;
}
```

```html
<main>
        <section class="portfolio">
            <div id="portfolio__headingContainer">
                <div id="headingContent" class="entry-image">
                    <h2 class="text-title entry-imgText">Portfolio</h2>
                </div> <!-- end entry-image -->
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio__content container content-container">
                
                <div id="portfolio_content_container">
                    <div class="portfolio__grid">

<!------------ Item 1 ------------>
                        <a href="#" id="TAFE" class="portfolio__item filter-projects TAFE" data-id="TAFE">
                            <img class="portfolio__image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature" alt="TAFE logo" />
                            <div class="portfolio__clientName">
                                <h3 id="TAFE" class="portfolio__clientName-text">TAFE (Theatre Arts For Everyone)</h3>
                            </div> <!-- end portfolio__clientName -->
                        </a>

                        <!------------ Item 2 ------------>
                        <a href="#" id="CAHQ" class="portfolio__item filter-projects CAHQ" data-id="CAHQ">
                            <img class="portfolio__image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature" alt="CAHQ Brochure" />
                            <div class="portfolio__clientName">
                                <h3 id="CAHQ" class="portfolio__clientName-text">College Admissions HQ</h3>
                            </div> <!-- end portfolio__clientName -->
                        </a>

                        <!------------ Item 3 ------------>
                        <a href="#" id="PWC" class="portfolio__item filter-projects PWC" data-id="PWC">
                            <img class="portfolio__image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature" alt="pilates wellness center logo" />
                            <div class="portfolio__clientName">
                                <h3 id="PWC" class="portfolio__clientName-text">Pilates Wellness Center of York</h3>
                            </div> <!-- end portfolio__clientName -->
                        </a>

                        <!------------ Item 4 ------------>
                        <a href="../pages/graphic_design/jane_daisy_general/jane_daisy_general.html" class="portfolio__item filter-projects" data-id=JDG">
                            <img class="portfolio__image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature" alt="jane dasie general logo" />
                            <div class="portfolio__clientName">
                                <h3 class="portfolio__clientName-text">Jane Daisy General</h3>
                            </div> <!-- end portfolio__clientName -->
                        </a>

                        <!------------ Item 5 ------------>
                        <a href="../pages/graphic_design/secondEncounter/secondEncounter.html" class="portfolio__item filter-projects" data-id="secondEncounter">
                            <img class="portfolio__image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature" alt="secondEncounter logo" />
                            <div class="portfolio__clientName">
                                <h3 class="portfolio__clientName-text">secondEncounter</h3>
                            </div> <!-- end portfolio__clientName -->
                        </a>

                        <!------------ Item 6 ------------>
                        <a href="#" class="portfolio__item filter-projects" data-id="DB">
                            <img class="portfolio__image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature" alt="Dobbs & Bishop" />
                            <div class="portfolio__clientName">
                                <h3 class="portfolio__clientName-text">Dobbs & Bishop Fine Cheese</h3>
                            </div> <!-- end portfolio__clientName -->
                        </a>

                        <!------------ Item 7 ------------>
                        <a href="../pages/graphic_design/yorkfest/yorkfest.html" class="portfolio__item filter-projects" data-id="Yorkfest">
                            <img class="portfolio__image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature" alt="Yorkfest Logo" />
                            <div class="portfolio__clientName">
                                <h3 class="portfolio__clientName-text">Yorkfest</h3>
                            </div> <!-- end portfolio__clientName -->
                        </a>

                        <!------------ Item 8 ------------>
                        <a href="../pages/graphic_design/lish/lish.html" class="portfolio__item filter-projects" data-id="Lish"> 
                            <img class="portfolio__image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature" alt="Lish Logo" />
                            <div class="portfolio__clientName">
                                <h3 class="portfolio__clientName-text">Lish</h3>
                            </div> <!-- end portfolio__clientName -->
                        </a>

                        <!------------ Item 9 ------------>
                        <a href="#" id="PE" class="portfolio__item filter-projects PE" data-id="PE">
                            <img class="portfolio__image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature" alt="Columbia-Wrightsville Bridge Book Cover" />
                            <div class="portfolio__clientName">
                                <h3 id="PE" class="portfolio__clientName-text">Photo Essays</h3>
                            </div> <!-- end portfolio__clientName -->
                        </a>

                    </div> <!-- end portfolio__grid--> 
                </div> <!-- end portfolio_content_container -->
            </div>
        </section>

        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="footer__contact-info">
                <div class="footer__name">
                    Emily Ray Ryan 
                </div> <!-- end footer__name-->
                <div class="footer__email">
                    <a href="mailto:emilyrayryan@gmail.com" target="_blank">emilyrayryan@gmail.com</a>
                </div> <!-- end footer__email -->
                <div class="footer__social">
                    <a class="footer__social-link" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-x2"></i></a> 
                </div> <!-- end footer__social -->
            </div> <!-- end footer__contact-info -->

            <div class="footer__copyright">
                &copy; 2021 - Website Designed and Developed by EmilyRayRyan
            </div> <!-- end footer__copyright -->
        </footer>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in using more **if** statements till it works while maintaining efficiency. But still if you want to reduce the amount of `if-else` then use switch statements.
You could do something like this.

```
const portfolioGrid = document.querySelector('.portfolio__grid');
let children = portfolioGrid.childNodes;
const findTerm = (num) => {
  if (children[1].classList.contains(num)){
    return num;
  }
};
```

And then use **switch statement**  like this

```
switch(true){
     case findTerm(1):
          ///Do something
     break;
     case findTerm(2):
          ///Do something
     break;
     case findTerm(3):
          ///Do something
     break;
     .
     .
     .
     .
     case findTerm(n):
          ///Do something
     break;
}
```

Here `findTerm(n)` is similar to `children[1].classList.contains(n)`.
Its not the best but still it makes the code much more readable.
Hope this helps you in some or the other way....